# Cocos2d - Sprite not animating

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a sprite that I'm adding to a scene and applying an animation to it but the animation isn't starting.
Here is the code, the frames have already been added to the array (explosionFrames) and I can see the frames individually when I apply them to the sprite.

```
CCSprite *expoSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:explosionFrames[0]];

expoSprite.position = bombSprite.position;


CCAnimation *explosionAnimation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:explosionFrames];


[expoSprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:explosionAnimation],nil]];


[n addChild:expoSprite];
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how do you create explosionFrames? Do you call stopAllActions somewhere, or re-run the animation action in a loop (ie every frame in a scheduled selector?)

Comment: The explosionFrames is a NSMutableArray and the frames are added to it from a CCSpriteBatchNode

Comment: can you post the actual code? As well as the context for the above code, ie what function it is in and where or how this function gets called?

Comment: what is the <n> object in above 'code' ?  disclose your code please.

Comment: n is a CCSpriteBatchNode, I haven't revealed surrounding code as I've been able to isolate this code as the problem code

Comment: @LukeHaas obviously not isolated enough no ? does n have a running parent ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg turned out to be isolated enough. The issue was the CCAnimation missing this: delay:0.1f

Answer (score 1):

Have you overridden `onEnter` on `n`'s class?

Did you remember to call `[super onEnter]`?

```
-(void) onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
    //Other code
}
```

This is practically always the problem when I have a node that isn't running actions.

Comment: or adding the sprite as child to a node that is not in the 'running' state. In this case, OP seems to be using CCSprite, thus unless the base cocos2d class was doctored, i suspect onEnter is appropriately called.

Answer (score -1):

First, you should add sprite as a child before running any actions. Second, you can write

`[expoSprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:explosionAnimation],nil]];`

if you going to add something to sequence or

`[expoSprite runAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:explosionAnimation]];`

instead of

`[expoSprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:explosionAnimation],nil]];`